# How to resolve a dependency based on attributes on a controller in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to implement caching in our Data Access layer in an ASP.NET Core `MVC` project as painlessly as possible. The main issue is that we don't want to read from the cache on all pages, only on some. The example below should illustrate the kind of setup we have:

```
[UseCache]
public class ControllerA : Controller 
{
    public ControllerA(IBuilder builder)
    {
        // Should resolve an IBuilder with a CacheService
    }   
}

public class ControllerB : Controller 
{
    public ControllerB(IBuilder builder)
    {
        // Should resolve an IBuilder with a NullCacheService
    }   
}

public class Builder : IBuilder
{
    public Builder(ICacheService cacheService)
    {
        // The type of the resolved ICacheService depends on the UseCache 
        // attribute on any of the object that depends on this IBuilder
    }
}

public class CacheService : ICacheService 
{
    public Object Get(string key, Func<Object> getValue) 
    {
        // Check if the value is cached against Key and return it if it's not
        // Obviously needs a lot more here regarding caching timeframes, expiry etc
    }
}

public class NullCacheService : ICacheService 
{
    public Object Get(string key, Func<Object> getValue) 
    {
        // Don't do anything with key, just do the work in getValue and return it
    }   
}

public class UseCacheAttribute : Attribute 
{

}
```

I know [Autofac can deal with resolving dependencies using attributes](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html#attribute-based-metadata) but

1. The Autofac.Extras.AttributeMetadata package is not support in ASP.NET Core MVC
2. Even if it were supported, I can't see how it would support attribute detection on the objects that contain this one.

I'm happy to introduce a new IoC framework, we're not tied to Autofac or the default IoC implemention.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible? What would be considered a better caching solution?

Comment: According to [Autofac.Extras.AttributeMetadata v4.0.1 release notes](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extras.AttributeMetadata/releases/tag/v4.0.1) you could use `Autofac.Features.AttributeFilters` which are supported in .net core.

Comment: @Sakis This is true but doesn't allow you to use your own attributes as far as I could tell - that requires you to register AttributedMetadataModule [which is in Autofac.Extras.AttributeMetadata](https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/D6EFF2D8.htm), and that's not going to be ported to .NET Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm happy to introduce a new IoC framework, we're not tied to Autofac or the default IoC implemention.

I'm not that familiar with Autofac, but I am familiar with Simple Injector, so I can show you how to apply such registration with Simple Injector:

```
var cache = new CacheService();
container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IBuilder),
    Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration<Builder>(
        () => new Builder(cache),
        container),
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType.GetCustomAttribute<UseCacheAttribute>() != null);

container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IBuilder),
    Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration<Builder>(
        () => new Builder(new NullCacheService()), 
        container),
    c => !c.Handled);
```

This registration is a bit complicated because you wish to change the dependency of the `Builder` type based on the consumer of `Builder`. Lookup up the 'chain' up to the consumer of the consumer is something that Simple Injector does not support, because it can easily result in incorrect behavior, especially when the middle consumer has a lifestyle other than transient. That's the conditional registration are for `IBuilder` and not for `ICacheService`.

Comment: This looks like the way we're going to implement it. I'm not able to verify this works at the moment (I'm having issues getting Simple Injector's crosswire method working with ASP.NET Core Identity) but it looks like it should work. Thanks! I'll report back if I have any issues ;)

Comment: There is some information about cross-wiring Identity stuff in the docs: https://simpleinjector.org/aspnetcore#working-with-asp-net-core-identity. If you have any particular questions, you might want to post a new question either [here](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/new) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: That guide is very bare-bones, it doesn't really explain cross-wiring. I can't find anything in the docs on CrossWire either. That's important because I've got a custom implementation, and I really don't want to have to wire up all the Identity dependencies... Will ask questions elsewhere :)

Comment: This did work but the example was over-simplified and neglected to include situations where a Builder was a dependency of something other than the Controller and the CacheAttribute information wasn't cascading down. As Steven said, "Lookup up the 'chain' up to the consumer of the consumer is something that Simple Injector does not support". So I think that's the end of this approach for us.

Comment: @ MatthewDunlop, lease move this discussion to Github. It's important for me and the other SI maintainers to understand your troubles to be able to improve the integration package and the documentation. Would you be so kind to explain in a new Github issue your struggles?

Comment: @MatthewDunlop I used this in one of my project, it definitely works on IoC chaining.  The beauty of this approach is that if you use passive attribute, actions are only wired and evaluated if there's an attribute.